# Dependency injection in PHP and DIC

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I have a bone to pick with dependency injection. It seems like such a simple concept has led to a lot of confusion amongst many, and the 'right' way to it seems to spiral out of control in terms of complexity. In keeping things really simple I just want to know:

Is it good practice if I use standard functions to register my dependencies, like this:

```
function someObject() {
  return new someObject();
}
```

And can I pass parameters?

```
function someObject($param1) {
  return new someObject($param1);
}
```

Finally how about using a simple custom container class:

```
class Dependencies {
  function someObject($param1) {
    return new someObject($param1);
  }
}
```

And using it:

```
class SomeClass {
  public function __construct(Dependencies $dependencies) {
    $this->dependencies = $dependencies
  }

  public function methodNeedsDependency() {
    $param1 = 'one';
    $task = $this->dependencies->someObject($param1);
  }
}
```

I guess what I'm asking is, is this a decent attempt at a *very simple* implementation of a DIC? Or are there some underlying major issues bubbling under the surface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SomeClass` is a factory, designed to create some instance with some exact config given, then yes, we could say this is very simple implementation of DIC.

Issues here? Well, let's say You want to create `someObject` with other constructor params.

Solutions:

1. Create another `SomeClass` factory that will pass other params. It's redundant solution that also mixes two application layers ( config with object creation layer ).
2. Parametrize `methodNeedsDependency` with params that will be passed to `someObject`. It's something that allows You to postpone in code config creation.
3. and last but the most proper way: DIC should be flexible, should allow You to create any service instances with any dependencies, and all of configuration should be stored in configuration layer. Separation of concerns - try to make DIC unaware of what object type is creating. Just let him make objects that You described somewhere else.

There are a lot of other issues also, like for example what if You would like to have only one instance of given class for whole DIC ( it's easy to "if" it, but that's another workaround to proper solution ) or what with circular references.

This discussion can go on and on with other issues about architecture in general, like "services should be stateless" what makes it unnecesary to have more then one, but answer to your question are those 3 points. Of course remember it's not ultimate-mega-hiper answer for DIC. It's just my way of seeing it ;-)

Comment: Simple yet thorough answer... So when you say "_create some instance with some exact config given_" do you mean the config needs to be given at the container level? Or is it reasonable to _parametized_ as mentioned in  step 2, where this is passed in as an argument at a later stage?

Comment: Config should be given on...well, config layer :) create configuration file ( YAML, XML, TXT, whatever ) where You say what exactly You want to pass to instance. Good example is configuration for Symfony container. Look it up how services are being defined there.